# Creating an animated gif with PIL that does not loop

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gifsicle

I've been able to create animated gifs that loop infinitely using PIL without an issue, usually ending up with something like

`final_image.save('/path/to/images/some.gif,
  save_all=True,
  append_images=frames_images,
  duration=frame_speeds,
  loop=0)`

I am now in a situation where I would like to create a gif that plays a single time and does not loop.  The PIL docs I used¹ are pretty clear about the loop argument but don't offer any advice for my situation:

> loop : int
>   The number of iterations. Default 0 (meaning loop indefinitely).

0 causes it to loop infinitely.  1 causes it loop once (play two times).  I have tried options like -1 and None but can't find a working argument.  I am currently using a work around where I invoke gifsicle afterwards to remove the loop entirely but was hoping PIL would support this natively

¹ - https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/format_gif-pil.html

Comment: Surely loop=1 means it loops (and thus plays) once, not twice as you suggest?

Comment: @Gavin Unfortunately no, loop=1 seems to result in the sequence playing two times

Comment: Might depend on the version of imageio / pillow - see the following merge request as it seems to be an incompatibility between older versions of imageio and _some_ gif players (ie chrome for instance). [imageio merge request](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/pull/237)

Comment: @user1026361 it appears you have stumbled upon a bug in the current distribution of the Pillow for Python. I was able to replicate your issue, in fact the GIF will always loop `n+1` times when passed `loop=n` - I can only suggest submitting this as a bug with the maintainer and using your workaround to enforce a single loop for the time being. Note that @Gavin is correct, the issue is relevant - Chrome loops twice for `n=1`, while some viewers only loop once (and others loop the same .gif endlessly)

Comment: Thank you @Grismar and Gavin - I've never encountered an issue with PIL and hadn't considered this might be a bug.  I will keep my work around in play and follow up with the maintainer

Answer (score 9):

If you are using Pillow, you can leave out the loop argument. That'll ensure no loop.
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving
Also to note, duration is in milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: I don't know why that's not the accepted answer. It works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What a funny coincidence. I have a code that shows a GIF one iteration and then freezes until the mp3 file is finished... but I need a GIF that loops infinitely.

The only difference is I used the library moviepy.

**Working solution:**

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import moviepy.editor as mp


# Import the audio(Insert to location of your audio instead of audioClip.mp3)
audio = AudioFileClip("PATH/TO/MP3_FILE")

clip = VideoFileClip("PATH/TO/GIF_FILE").set_duration(audio.duration)


# Set the audio of the clip
clip = clip.set_audio(audio)


clip_resized = clip.resize((1920, 1080)) 


# Export the clip
clip_resized.write_videofile("movie_resized.mp4", fps=24)
```